# meaning of inline assembly in the linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, inline-assembly, llvm-ir

I would like to know the meaning of %P3 in the following code:

```
#define get_user(x, ptr)                        \
({                                  \
    int __ret_gu;                           \
    register __inttype(*(ptr)) __val_gu asm("%edx");        \
    __chk_user_ptr(ptr);                        \
    might_fault();                          \
    asm volatile("call __get_user_%P3"              \
             : "=a" (__ret_gu), "=r" (__val_gu)         \
             : "0" (ptr), "i" (sizeof(*(ptr))));        \
    (x) = (__typeof__(*(ptr))) __val_gu;                \
    __ret_gu;                           \
})
```

Moreover in the LLVM IR the code is mapped to:

```
call { i32*, i64 } asm sideeffect "call __get_user_${3:P}", "={ax},={edx},0,i,~{dirflag},~{fpsr},~{flags}"(i32* %tmp73, i64 4)
```

My understanding is that this is actually calling a specific function __get_user_X in arch/x86/lib/getuser.S, but it's not clear which one in particular (__get_user_4?).

Finally, I would like to understand the difference between %P and %p.

Answer (score 1):

I think %P3 indicates that the X in __get_user_X is depend on "i" (sizeof(*(ptr)). Such as sizeof(*(ptr)) may be 1, 2, 4, 8.

The 3 means the third parameter inside the asm volatile("...") statement. And %P is for string concatenation.

About %P and %p difference, I guess it's for string specification, but I am not sure. I copied following sentences from GCC user manual:

```
%p Substitutes the standard macro predefinitions for the current target machine.
   Use this when running cpp.
%P Like ‘%p’, but puts ‘__’ before and after the name of each predefined macro,
   except for macros that start with ‘__’ or with ‘_L’, where L is an uppercase
   letter. This is for ISO C.
```

Comment: That [documentation seems to be for "spec files"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) which doesn't seem related to GAS